# calculate sum of numbers closest to a given number

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, sum

I want to find out what is the best way to do this in C#:
I have a array of lets say 20 numbers, and then one more additional variable.
I want to get the sum of the numbers which is closest to the given variable.
Lets say, I have 1.1, 1.5, 1.7, 1.9, 2.2, 3.1, 3.2, 1,5, 4.5, 4.1. And then the additional variable has value of 5. 
I want to get the sum of some numbers in the array which will be closest to the given number, and once I'll get that number, remove those numbers from the list and add them to a new array. 
Every comment is welcomed.
Thanks

Comment: How do you determine which is number is close to 5?

Comment: Only one distinct number can be the closest to another

Comment: I think it means: 1.1 + 1.5 + 2.2 = 4.7 which is closer to 5 than 4.5

Comment: What's the answer for your example?  1.1 and 4.1?

Comment: @L.B if you get the sum of 3.1 and 1.9 you'll get exactly 5.

Comment: @Krispy yes, that's what I meant, thanks

Answer (score 4):

You are describing the optimization problem for **[Subset Sum Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)**.

The problem is [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete), so there is no known polynomial solution to it.

However, since the input is fairly small scale - an exponential solution of **checking all subsets** is feasible, since there are only 2^20 ~= 1000000 (a bit more, actually, but close enough for estimating run time)

Pseudo code should be something like:

```
getClosestSum(list,sum,number):
  if (list is empty):
      return sum
  candidate1 <- getClosest(list[1:],sum,number)
  candidate2 <- getClosest(list[1:],sum+list[0],number)
  if (abs(number-candidate1) < abs(number-candidate2)):
      return candidate1
  else:
      return candidate2
```