# translate approximate algorithm for subset sum into php code

Tags: php, optimization, subset-sum, np

[Cross-posted in MathExchange to elicit more responses](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/473404/91317).

================================================================================

I was writing my original question in StackOverflow, when I realized it was asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13634225/80353).

Turns out I have what is known as a subset sum problem, so I went to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) and found this part.

```
The algorithm for the approximate subset sum problem is as follows:
 initialize a list S to contain one element 0.
 for each i from 1 to N do
   let T be a list consisting of xi + y, for all y in S
   let U be the union of T and S
   sort U
   make S empty 
   let y be the smallest element of U 
   add y to S 
   for each element z of U in increasing order do
      //trim the list by eliminating numbers close to one another
      //and throw out elements greater than s
     if y + cs/N < z ≤ s, set y = z and add z to S 
 if S contains a number between (1 − c)s and s, output yes, otherwise no
```

But I have problem understanding the pseudo code written in wikipedia.

For instance, I thought the objective is to find the closest set of numbers that can match S.

*But here S is a list. What is this S list with element 0?*

*And what on earth is  `if y + cs/N < z ≤ s`? How do I even write this out in code?*

I was hoping someone can help me translate this into php code.

At least I am more familiar with that. It need not be a full translation.

**As long as the answers make me understand this approximate algorithm enough for me to write it in php code myself, that will do.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the sub-questions you posted on math.stackexchange.com one by one:

**What is the difference between the big `S` and the small `s`?** The big `S` is a list variable which is initially the list `[0]` and is modified over the course of the execution of the code. The little `s` is a number that remains constant. Specifically, `s` is the number from this question:

> Given a set of integers and an integer *s*, does any non-empty subset sum to *s*?

**But what *is* `S`, anyway?** Roughly speaking, `S` represents the set of all "useful" sums that we can make using the elements we've seen so far (if I'm not mistaken).

**Does "a list with element 0" mean a list containing a single number, which is zero?** Yes, that's what that means.

**What does `y + cs/N < z ≤ s` mean?** It means that `y + c*s/N < z` and `z ≤ s`. So the `if` will fail whenever `y + c*s/N ≥ z` *or* `z > s` (or both).

And some questions you didn't ask, but which seem likely to come up:

**What is `N`?** `N` is the number of elements in the set we are given.

**What is `xi`?** `xi` is the *i*-th element of the set we are given.